# Handling Nested Delimiters in perl

Tags: perl, delimiter

```
use strict;   
use warnings; 

my %result_hash = (); 
my %final_hash  = (); 
Compare_results(); 

foreach my $key (sort keys %result_hash ){ 
  print "$key \n"; 
  print "$result_hash{$key} \n"; 
} 

sub Compare_results 
{ 

  while ( <DATA> ) 
  { 
   my($instance,$values) = split /\:/, $_; 
   $result_hash{$instance} = $values; 

   } 
} 
__DATA__ 
1:7802315095\d\d,7802315098\d\d;7802025001\d\d,7802025002\d\d,7802025003\d\ d,7802025004\d\d,7802025005\d\d,7802025006\d\d,7802025007\d\d
2:7802315095\d\d,7802025002\d\d,7802025003\d\d,7802025004\d\d,7802025005\d\d,7802025006\d\d,7802025007\d\d
```

Output

```
1 
7802315095\d\d,7802315098\d\d;7802025001\d\d,7802025002\d\d,7802025003\d\d,7802025004\d\d,7802025005\d\d,7802025006\d\d,7802025007\d\d 

2 
7802315095\d\d,7802025002\d\d,7802025003\d\d,7802025004\d\d,7802025005\d\d,7802025006\d\d,7802025007\d\d
```

Iam trying to fetch value of each key and again trying to split the comma seperated value from result hash , if i find a semicolon in any value i would want to store the left and right values in separate hash keys.

Something like below

```
1.#split the value of result_hash{$key}  again by , and see whether any chunk is seperated by ;
2. #every chunk without ; and value on left  with ; should be stored in   
 @{$final_hash{"eto"}} =   ['7802315095\d\d','7802315098\d\d','7802025002\d\d','7802025003\d\d','7802025004\d\d','7802025005\d\d','7802025006\d\d','7802025007\d\d']  ;
3.#Anything found on the right side of ; has to be stored in  
 @{$final_hash{"pro"}} = ['7802025001\d\d'] ;
```

Is there a way that i can handle everything in the subroutine? Can i make the code more simpler

Update :

I tried splitting the string in a single shot, but its just picking the values with semicolon and ignoring everything

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %result_hash ){
#   print "$key \n";
#   print "$result_hash{$key} \n";
my ($o,$t) = split(/,|;/, $result_hash{$key});
   print "Left : $o \n";
   print "Left : $t \n";
   #push @{$final_hash{"eto"}}, $o;
   #push @{$final_hash{"pro"}} ,$t;
 }
```

}

**My updated code after help**

```
sub Compare_results
{   
  open my $fh, '<', 'Data_File.txt' or die $!;
  # split by colon and further split by , and ; if any (done in insert_array)
  my %result_hash = map { chomp; split ':', $_ } <$fh> ; 
  foreach  ( sort { $a <=> $b }  (keys %result_hash) )
  { 
     ($_ < 21) 
        ? insert_array($result_hash{$_}, "west")
        : insert_array($result_hash{$_}, "east");
  } 
}


 sub insert_array()
 {
   my ($val,$key) = @_;
   foreach my $field (split ',', $val)
   {   
     $field =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;    # /  turn off editor coloring
     if ($field !~ /;/) {
        push @{ $file_data{"pto"}{$key} }, $field ;
     }
     else {
       my ($left, $right) = split ';', $field;
       push  @{$file_data{"pto"}{$key}}, $left if($left ne '') ;
       push @{$file_data{"ero"}{$key}}, $right if($right ne '')  ;
    }
   }  
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Nice thought, but if you split on either `/[,;]/` how do you tell which ones are the "right" ones (right of `;`)?  It returns a list of all fields, between either `,` or `;`, in whatever order they happen.  (What you wrote assigns the list to two (2) scalars, so you only get the first two elements after the split.)

Comment: I edited your addition -- moved the long comment to its own line so not to have to scroll to read it, and added a comment `# / ...` by regex that turns off wrong red coloring by the editor. (It does that often -- after a regex everything turns red.)  If you don't like this please revert changes -- click on "edited (time)" above my username and you'll see revisions, with buttons by each. One of them says "rollback", click on it by the revision you want to roll back to.

Comment: @zdim : Would you let me know how to split the data which has two delimiters ex : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7;8,9,10,11,12 and i would want to store everything after ; in an array and right in another array. would be please help me with a  one shot split function . O/P array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and array2 =[8,9,10,11,12]

Comment: For right now, a two-pass variation of the last example in my answer.  First pop -- `@left = split ",", (/([^;]+)/)[0]` and `@right = split ",", (/;([^;]+)/)[0];`. This is if the string to process is in `$_` -- if it's in a variable, use `($str =~ /.../)[0]`. Add `say for @left` to see it.  The `(...)[0]` is needed because a match returns _a list_ and if you pass it to `split` it evaluates in scalar context, as 1 (length).   A truly one-shot is harder since you'd get one list, but need to split it into two.  I'll post another comment if I come up with better.

Comment: But is it trying to split the same data twice 
sure, is this worth a new question ?

Comment: I wouldn't -- it's practically the same question as this one. If you really need it in one statement it may be interesting -- but it may be a bit arbitrary, to push for one statement.

Comment: @zdim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691215/split-the-data-with-3-delimiters-and-store-it-in-2-separate-arrays-at-a-time   , Asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**    Added a two-pass regex, at the end

---

Just proceed systematically, analyze the string step by step. The fact that you need consecutive splits and a particular separation rule makes it unwieldy to do in one shot.  Better have a clear method than a monster statement.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;   
use feature 'say';

my (%result_hash, %final_hash); 

Compare_results(); 

say "$_ => $result_hash{$_}" for sort keys %result_hash;
say '---';
say "$_ => [ @{$final_hash{$_}} ]" for sort keys %final_hash;

sub Compare_results 
{   
    %result_hash = map { chomp; split ':', $_ } <DATA>;

    my (@eto, @pro);
    foreach my $val (values %result_hash)
    {   
        foreach my $field (split ',', $val)
        {   
            if ($field !~ /;/) { push @eto, $field }
            else { 
                my ($left, $right) = split ';', $field;
                push @eto, $left;
                push @pro, $right;
            }
        }    
    }        
    $final_hash{eto} = \@eto;
    $final_hash{pro} = \@pro;
    return 1;                  # but add checks above
}
```

There are some inefficiencies here, and no error checking, but the method is straightforward.  If your input is anything but smallish please change the above to process line by line, what you clearly know how to do.  It prints

```
1 => ...  (what you have in the question)
---
eto => [ 7802315095\d\d 7802315098\d\d 7802025002\d\d 7802025003\d\ d ...
pro => [ 7802025001\d\d ]
```

Note that your data does have one loose `\d\ d`.

---

We don't need to build the whole hash `%result_hash` for this but only need to pick the part of the line after `:`.  I left the hash in since it is declared global so you may want to have it around. If it in fact isn't needed on its own this simplifies

```
sub Compare_results {
    my (@eto, @pro);
    while (<DATA>) {
        my ($val) = /:(.*)/;
        foreach my $field (split ',', $val)
        # ... same
    }
    # assign to %final_hash, return from sub
}
```

Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments.

---

Just for the curiosity's sake, here it is in two passes with regex

```
sub compare_rx {
    my @data = map { (split ':', $_)[1] } <DATA>;
    $final_hash{eto} = [ map { /([^,;]+)/g  } @data ];
    $final_hash{pro} = [ map { /;([^,;]+)/g } @data ];
    return 1;
}
```

This picks all characters which are not `,` or `;`, using the *negated character class*, `[^,;]`. So that is up to the first either of them, left to right. It does this globally, `/g`, so it keeps going through the string, collecting all fields that are "left of" `,` or `;`. Then it cheats a bit, picking all `[^,;]` that are right of `;`. The `map` is used to do this for all lines of data.

If `%result_hash` is needed build it instead of `@data` and then pull the values from it with `my @values = values %hash_result` and feed the map with `@values`.

Or, broken line by line (again, you can build `%result_hash` instead of taking `$data` directly)

```
my (@eto, @pro);
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($data) = /:(.*)/;
    push @eto, $data =~ /([^,;]+)/g; 
    push @pro, $data =~ /;([^,;]+)/g;
}
```

Comment: @LearningCpp I updated the answer -- completed the code to a full program, tested with your data, added some comments.

Comment: Thanks @zdim , i have used your last peice of code, but its appending an extra \ to \d (i.e \\d), Also could you please explain map { chomp;(split ':', $_)[1] }; i added chomp for eliminating empties

Comment: @LearningCpp  That's strange -- it's not adding it in my tests (what I posted as output is copied form my terminal), as it shouldn't.  It's the same output for regex.  The line is as follows. It `chomp`s the newline. Then it splits by `:`, resulting in two fields. The `map` makes is so that it does this for every line, and the whole list is sent on.  So these are pairs, and you can assign that directly to a hash.  This is legit: `my %h = (1, 'one', 2, 'two');` It pairs them up, `key => value, ...`  A very nice way to assign to a hash.

Comment: @LearningCpp  It's very late here and I'll go now (for those zzzz). Let me know, I will be back in a few hours.  I can add to the post if these comments aren't good enough.

Comment: Here is my output , iam using the map code you posted
         ['7802261004\\d\\d',
          '7802261046\\d\\d',
          '7802261064\\d\\d',
          '7802261186\\d\\d',
          '7802293001\\d\\d'
        ];
Looking into whats gone wrong

Comment: @zdim , Oh you are just picking the part after : , and not worried about the values before : , is nt it  ? for the statement map { (split ':', $_)[1] } <DATA>; i actually have need those values also, i would want to store 1 to 20 in a seperate hash and 21 to 40 in other

Comment: @LearningCpp  In the regex solution, I `split` the whole line on `:` -- so to get rid of `1:` and `2:`.  This is instead of your `%result_hash`, and what I get are your original `$values`,  Then they are processed fully -- left of `,` or `;` goes into `eto`, right of `;` into `pro`. The regex itself you can use on the keys of your original `%result_hash` (the `$values`), if you actually need that hash.

Comment: @LearningCpp  If you do need to have that `%result_hash`, instad of `my @data = map { ... } <DATA>` you can have `my @values = values %result_hash` and then use the regex on that, `[ map { ... } ] @values`.

Comment: @LearningCpp However, I recommend the first solution, if you need to also have `%result_hash`, or the second if you don't.  The regex is trickier.

Comment: @LearningCpp  As for doubles, `\\d`, that you mentiond -- there is no way they can be produced by any of this.  I take it that your data comes from elsewhere, not from `<DATA>` and that's where I would look for how `\\` happen.

Comment: @LearningCpp  Finally, if the "_1 to 20_" that you mention refer to the `1:` and `2:` in your `DATA`, then you are saying that you do need the `%result_hash`.  Then use the hash instead of parsing data directly -- see one of the comments above, and the method in the first solution.  All this is much easier to do and much more flexible in the loop based solutions.  Regex can be a bit britle, harder to tweak around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123940/discussion-between-learningcpp-and-zdim).

Comment: the extra slash is appended by dumper delibrately. :)

Comment: @LearningCpp  I am here now (it's morning here), if you are up for a chat let me know.  Otherwise -- is this OK now?  There are a few solutions here, which all work (tested with data you posted).  If something isn't working let me know precisely what it is so that I can help you debug -- the posted code has to be work for shown data.  Also, please confirm -- you do need to have that `%result_hash`, is that correct?

Comment: Added my final version

Comment: @LearningCpp  I looked over your code, seems fine -- I'll look more tomorrow (need to sleep now!) and will drop a line.  Thank you for the attribution. Let me know if there are more questions or if they come up.